# Visual Studio 2008 Resource Editor

Tags: user-interface, visual-c++, resources, pixel

What is the unit used in Resource Editor? It does not seem to be pixel.. Than how to use pixel, or is there a option to use pixel?
Here is a screen shot...
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think its called dialog box units.

here are some tutorials to compute the units.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/145994

http://www.codeguru.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-336807.html

Comment: Yes, and it's dependent on the size of the dialog font. There's no way to use pixels with the resource editor.